# Omniauth-google-oauth2 not correctly passing "scope" for oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, google-oauth

First, the context: I'm writing a little web app to do some custom Google Analytics reporting for me.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

In my `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"]
    {
      :scope => "userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,analytics.readonly",
      :approval_prompt => "auto"
    }
end
```

When I get to the auth screen on google, it's only asking me for `userinfo.email` and `userinfo.profile` permissions, and nothing for `analytics.readonly`.

Looking at the URL when I'm auth'ing, I can see that it's only requesting the first two permissions. If I manually add the analytics permission, it grants the correct permissions. So, I've narrowed the issue down to

1. How I'm passing scope to the `omniauth-google-oauth2` strategy, or
2. How the strategy is handling/ignoring the scope hash.

Also, I have double-checked that the Analytics API is turned on for my OAuth keys in the Google API Console.

Answer (score 0):

Poorly formatted code, I was missing a comma after `ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"]`. Below is the fixed code.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"],
    {
      :scope => "userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,analytics.readonly",
      :approval_prompt => "auto"
    }
end
```